# Converting Excel formula into Python script for ArcGIS

Tags: python, excel, data-conversion

I have some fields that I need to bring together, average and then recategorize them so that I can rate them. I'm be doing this in ArcGIS.

I know how to do this in Excel in a two-step process:

1.

```
=(Field1 + Field2 + Field3)/3
```

2.

```
=IF([@[Field4]]>=10,3,IF([@[Field4]]>=5,2,IF([@[Field4]]>=0,1,IF([@[Field4]]=#N/A*,Null))))
```

There are fields that will have Null values.

The other formula needs to convert string (ranges) to a number, i.e. 0-5 = 1, then 6-10 = 2, etc.

Then I would use the previous to calculate what I need to do for those objects.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do? What are the "objects" you mentioned, and output are you trying to get? Could you give a concrete example with values similar to those you are using.

Comment: I have a vector layer in ArcGIS.

Comment: I have a vector layer in ArcGIS, that I need to calculate some attributes for. I want to use the field calculator(python/VB script) to take these attributes that already exist in the layer, and process them as above. Thanks

Comment: Improved wording and formatting, but I'm still not sure what he means in the last part.

Comment: you should ask this over at gis.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest to use pandas library to do the data handling with [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function.
For the first step you can do it with the [mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) function.
For the second step :

```
df['field 4'].loc[df['field 4']>=10]=3
df['field 4'].loc[(df['field 4']>=5) & (df['fiel 4']<10)]=2
df['field 4'].loc[(df['field 4']>=0) & (df['field 4']<5)]=1
df['field 4'].fillna(None)
```